# Parent view change its frame after dismissing modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers. When I present modally 'B' view controller in 'A' view controller and then dismiss it, view in 'A' view controller change its frame from {{0, 0}, {320, 480}} to {{0,0}, {0,0}}. All subviews do not change its positions but not responds.

Controller 'A' code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.logoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.view.backgroundColor = WHITE_C;
    buttonHeight = self.view.frame.size.height/5;
    buttonYPosition = self.view.frame.size.height - buttonHeight;
    buttonW = self.view.frame.size.width/2;
    [self configureButtons];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void) auth {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueToAuth sender:self];
}
```

Controller 'B' code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = ORANGE_C;

    UIImage * backArrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_orange.png"];
    UIBarButtonItem * back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:backArrow style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backToWelcomeScreen)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[back]];
}

#pragma mark - Buttons

- (void) backToWelcomeScreen {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Do somebody have any idea why it's happens?

I tried to set frame back by `viewDidAppear:` but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using autoLayout ?

Comment: @Vishu no, I do not use it.

Comment: How did you set up `A` and `B`?

Comment: @Wongzigii from Storyboard

Comment: @Vishu sorry, I understand your question incorrect. And, yes, I  use autoLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in:

`self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.logoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

After it removing app works well.

Answer (score 0):

Your seperator-view width and height depending on the button size, and you only set the button size in the viewdidload the next time you set the views frame the button size is nil